# remove &q; and load string using json.loads function

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load below json string using json.loads function in python.
but &q; is not a valid json object.

Is there a way for me to remove this? 
I've provided a sample below:

```
[{&q;Id&q;:1,&q;Name&q;:&q;Name}]
```

Comment: [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace)?

Answer (score 2):

Angular uses a special `escapeHtml` function for [transfer state](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/TransferState). You can find those `escapeHtml`/`unescapeHtml` functions [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/61bfa3d9dfc7c9daecde098aca595b731c3312a0/packages/platform-browser/src/browser/transfer_state.ts#L12-L32):

```js
export function escapeHtml(text: string): string {
  const escapedText: {[k: string]: string} = {
    '&': '&a;',
    '"': '&q;',
    '\'': '&s;',
    '<': '&l;',
    '>': '&g;',
  };
  return text.replace(/[&"'<>]/g, s => escapedText[s]);
}

export function unescapeHtml(text: string): string {
  const unescapedText: {[k: string]: string} = {
    '&a;': '&',
    '&q;': '"',
    '&s;': '\'',
    '&l;': '<',
    '&g;': '>',
  };
  return text.replace(/&[^;]+;/g, s => unescapedText[s]);
}
```

You can reproduce this escape function in python using the following code:

```py
import json

unescapedText = {
    '&a;': '&',
    '&q;': '"',
    '&s;': '\'',
    '&l;': '<',
    '&g;': '>',
}

def unescape(str):
    for key, value in unescapedText.items():
        str = str.replace(key, value)
    return str

state = "[{&q;Id&q;:1,&q;Name&q;:&q;Name&q;}]"
decoded = json.loads(unescape(state))

print(decoded)
```

repl.it: https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/AngularTransferStateDecode2

Answer (score 1):

try simple to `replace` the `&q;` with `"` double quotes

```
import json
data = '[{&q;Id&q;:1,&q;Name&q;:&q;Name&q;}]'
data = data.replace('&q;', '"')
print(json.loads(data))
```

**Output**

```
[{'Id': 1, 'Name': 'Name'}]
```

Comment: Actually I want to know the what type of encoding it is using because there are many tags being used like &l; for less than and many others. So I cant hard code everything.

Comment: you can create a regx to clean it.

Comment: data.replace(/&q;/g, '"');